# Is it possible to draw "uses" type relationship between types and methods in Visual Studio 2010's class designer?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, modeling, class-designer

I want to draw connections between types and methods showing the using relationship between them, i.e:

```
GlobalExecutor -> (uses) -> EndEffect -> (uses) -> RealTimeEffect
```

... in a tree-like manner.

Comment: Do you mean the Class Designer, or the UML Class Diagram?

Comment: I mean the class designer. Is there a uml class diagram in VS? I use mine by selecting some code files and selecting -> view class diagram from solution explorer.

Comment: @Joan: there's a UML Class Diagram in VS2010 Ultimate - maybe in some of the other versions, I don't know. It's real UML, unlike the class designer.

Comment: I see what you mean. I use the pro version, so likely don't have it. I guess that thing you mention can only be done using the uml not the class designer right?

Comment: @Joan: right. Note how a "uses" connection does not imply any change in the actual class. Hence, a "class designer" wouldn't "use" "uses".

Comment: Thanks John, I didn't know the class designer is used to actually design classes. I thought it's to make some diagram using your existing types, to make some sort of showcase.

Comment: @Joan: nope - that's why they call it the "Class Designer". Another unrelated FYI - when you right-click a project and choose "Properties", that's called the "Project Designer". They like the word "Designer" - :-)

Comment: I didn't know that. I guess that makes sense since that also changes the properties of the project. Thanks man. Btw should I close this question then?

Comment: No. I'll add my comments as an answer. If you like it, then accept it. This will help others asking the same question later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visual Studio Class Designer is not meant to create complete UML Class Diagrams. It's meant to design classes.

No part of the text of a class changes because of "uses" connections, so that functionality is not present in the Class Designer.

The Ultimate Edition of Visual Studio 2010 (and maybe other editions) has a new UML Modeling feature, including UML Class Models. This feature allows you to create Dependency connections between classes.

Comment: Btw how did you mark this as CW? I thought that feature was removed?

Comment: @Joan: it's removed for questions - not for answers.

Comment: I see John. I wouldn't mind this answer being non CW, but you know it better than me :O

Comment: @Joan: thanks, but it didn't feel right to get rep from telling you "no, you can't do that".

Comment: Np, IMO closure is better than uncertainty :O So at least now I don't have to look around to see if it's possible.